# Target file "lib\main.dart" not found while running $flutter run

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I changed nothing, just worked on my Flutter Aplication, after the day i wanted to flutter run --release my app, but it didn't worked and i got this error message: Target file "lib\main.dart" not found. The day before everything worked fine. After a couple of times i tried it on another app, where i didn't changed something for a couple of days. But some of my other apps are working fine. The normal running in Android Studio is working normally on every app. Does anybody knwo what's the problem here?

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXUlz.png)

[My Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVRS8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running your command on a different directory. Check your directory using `pwd` command on terminal.

Edit: As you use windows, make sure you open command line in your project directory.
See this tutorial.
https://www.lifewire.com/open-command-prompt-in-a-folder-5185505

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I run the command pwd in the terminal

Comment: Aren't you running flutter run --release on terminal? You just need to enter command `pwd` and see the output. Sorry, it seems you are using Windows. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks a lot, the command flutter run is working fine with windows powershell, so its perhaps an failure of android studio